# How do I determine the version of the SCOM agent installed on a server?

Tags: system-center, scom

Context first: We have two version of SCOM installed. An SCOM 2007 installation and a recently installed 2012 R2. After much swearing and dirty looks from a colleague one cubicle over I'm starting to figure this product out...

I can see that SCOM agent is installed on a particular server by checking for the windows service HealthService.

What I want to know is how do I tell which version of SCOM the agent is talking to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorted it out myself.

The version is captured in Program Files path..

```
e.g. C:\Program Files\System Center Operations Manager 2007
```

Now how do I withdraw my question because it had such an obvious answer...

Comment: You should find a "delete" link at the bottom of the question!

Answer (score 0):

This is the best case when you can find an answer to your question by yourself :)
BTW, you potentially may need to connect your SCOM2012 agents to the SCOM2007 management server and in that case, you will be able to see all your servers in your SCOM2007. In that case, you will be able to distinguish agent versions in SCOM console in "Administration" pane under "Device Management/Agent Managed" folder.

Good luck!
Roman.